# Change the content of loading spinner after certain of time without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

I have got a loading spinner for an AJAX calls. So, I would like to change the text of the display after 10 seconds to tell user "Please wait, still processing...". Users change business name from drop down list.

```js
function showAjaxLoader() {
  if ($('#loader').length <= 0) {
    $('body').append('<div style="display:none;"><div id="loader" class="stepLoader"><p>Loading...</p></div></div>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loader p').replaceWith('<span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">Please wait, still processing...<span>');
    }, 10000);
  } else {
    $('#loader .spinner').remove();
  }
}
```

This solution works fine. However, when a user changes the business name the loader still shows the "Please wait, still processing..." message. It should be showing "loading ..." message.  I am calling this function;

```
 beforeSend: showAjaxLoader(),
```

Any suggestions would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as an option you may want to remove your loader from DOM completely. I expect you to also have method `hideAjaxLoader` that should do `$('#loader').remove()`.

or if you use `showAjaxLoader` for both operation it would better rename it to `toggleAjaxLoader` and make full clean-up in `else`, so instead of `$('#loader .spinner').remove();` you have `$('#loader').remove();`

One side suggestion, it will be a good practice if you will clear a timeout if data arrived earlier than in 10 seconds.